# identityreducer in the new Hadoop API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I spent almost a day but couldn't figure out how to use IdentityReducer in the new Hadoop API. All references or classes I can find are with the old API. And obviously mixing up old API idetntitreducer class in the new API codebase doesn't go well. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to add a bit more detail: import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer is what I can find wherever I look but this isn't a new API class.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Mainly because in the new API `Mapper` and `Reducer` are classes instead of interfaces, they are the new replacement of IdentityMapper/Reducer.

So you just have to use `Mapper.class` and `Reducer.class` to get the identity.

Comment: And if you don't explicitly set the mapper or reducer class, the identity version is used by default

Answer (score 0):

Have a look :

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityReducer.html

Its for hadoop stable version

Answer (score 0):

**Hadoop Streaming - Hadoop 1.0.2**

According to [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.2/streaming.html), the command is

```
-x org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityX
```

where x = mapper or reducer and X = Mapper or Reducer respectively.

I tested myself and works.